# ContextErrorException when submit form with A2lix

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, translation, stofdoctrineextensions

For a multilingual form I use [Gedmo](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) Translatable combined with [A2lix](http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/1.4.html) and I use [personal translations](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations), so for 1 entity I have 1 translation : Categ and CategTranslation.

To show the form everything is alright, but when I submit it I've this error :

> ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Immo\AnnonceBundle\Entity\CritereCategTranslation::__construct(), called in /var/www/kimsufi/asimmobilier/vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle/Form/DataMapper/GedmoTranslationMapper.php on line 70 and defined in /var/www/kimsufi/asimmobilier/src/Immo/AnnonceBundle/Entity/CritereCategTranslation.php line 29

This is my CategType :

```
->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
                    'translatable_class' => 'Immo\AnnonceBundle\Entity\CritereCateg',
                    'locales' => array('fr', 'en'),
                    'required' => false,
                    'fields' => array(
                        'libelle' => array(
                            'field_type' => 'text',
                            'locale_options' => array(
                                'en' => array(
                                    'label' => 'Libellé du critère (en) :',
                                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Example : Convenience, proximity, etc.')
                                ),
                                'fr' => array(
                                    'label' => 'Libellé du critère (fr) :',
                                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Exemple : A proximité, commodités, etc.')
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
             );
```

My CritereCategTranslation :

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="criterecateg_translations",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="lookup_unique_idx", columns={
 *         "locale", "object_id", "field"
 *     })}
 * )
 */
class CritereCategTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{

    /**
     * Convenient constructor
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function __construct($locale, $field, $value)
    {
        $this->setLocale($locale);
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($value);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CritereCateg", inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $object;


}
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove _construct method. You don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, I found this before your answer, but thanks. :)